# How to save the image on html page so it should not remove on refreshing the page

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want that the pic I am saving on database it should appear on users profile on html page. it should not remove on refreshing the page.

views.py

```
def userpic(request):
if request.method =="POST":
    user= request.user.id
    image = json.loads(request.body)['new_image'][0].split(',')[1]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(image)
    filename = 'static/images/image.png'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(imgdata)
        print os.path.abspath(filename)
    attend = attendence.objects.create(user_id=user,user_pic=filename)
    attend.save()

    return HttpResponse('success')
```